# Отфильтровать столбец DataFrame по длине строки

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
```

> загрузила определенный файл с базой данных

```
data = pd.read_csv('data-20150325T0100-structure-20150325T0100.csv', sep=';')
```

> почистила данные

```
data2=our_data.dropna(subset = ['Tel1'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Мне нужно из этой базы данных убрать телефоны(столбец `Tel1`), которые имеют длину более 16 чисел и менее 11 чисел
>   попробовала данный метод

```
data2.query( str('Tel1') != 11)
```

> выдает ошибку `ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'bool'> given`
>   как исправить? есть ли способ по другому убрать данные с определенным значением из столбца?

Comment: Замените пожалуйста картинку с данными на текст.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
data2 = data2[data2['Tel1'].str.len().between(11, 16)]
```

Пример:

```
In [21]: data2
Out[21]:
                 Tel1
0          1234567890
1         12345678901
2        123456789012
3       1234567890123
4      12345678901234
5     123456789012345
6    1234567890123456
7   12345678901234567
8  123456789012345678

In [22]: data2[data2['Tel1'].str.len().between(11, 16)]
Out[22]:
               Tel1
1       12345678901
2      123456789012
3     1234567890123
4    12345678901234
5   123456789012345
6  1234567890123456
```

PS в будущем постарайтесь приводить в вопросе [примеры входных данных в таком виде чтобы их можно было скопировать и также приводить пример данных, которые вы хотите получить на выходе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: спасибо, сработало! возможно поможете с вопросом о том, как в столбце Tel1 преобразовать номера разного формата '8-902-657-09-50; 8(8442) 94-39-54; 89272555572; (884463) 2-64-71; 8 903 371 40 73' в единый формат +7-777-777-77-77. (только русски номера)?  возможно по аналогии с временем 'print(pd.Tel1('2016-03-01', format='%Y-%m-%d'))'  как точно не могу понять

Comment: @user329688, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)

Comment: @user329688, задайте пожалуйста новый вопрос. Комментарии не предназначены для полноценных вопросов/ответов и в комментариях невозможно отформатировать код.